# require an es6 module into an es5 module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

This is a strange issue, but I'm trying to require an es6 module into a section of my application that is using es5.

```
es6file.js

import moment from 'moment'
etc...


es5file.js

var config = require('../../../es6file')
etc...
```

and I keep getting an error of `Unexpected token import`

This, of course, makes sense. But I'm wondering if there is an easy way to allow myself to import this file without updating my entire application to handle imports instead of requires.

Comment: You can use babel-node to transpile your code on the fly, but this is not recommended for production, otherwise, you just have to transpile it down to es5 code. `npx babel-node es5file.js`

Comment: You could also use webpack

Comment: Is this `nodejs`, as require is not standard ES5 import either, it's commonJS, and you must be using some sort of loader / transpiler if this is clientside Javascript.  We need more info here..

Comment: @Keith, you are correct, I'm using Node and I believe this is commonJS

Comment: Try renaming your `es6file.js` to `es6file.esm`, unfortunately nodejs doesn't default to es6 for .js files.